# After open Fancybox-2, send the focus in fancybox window

Tags: jquery, focus, fancybox-2, wai-aria, accessibility

For accessibility, I try to send the focus in the Fancybox window once it is opened.

I add a tabindex to 0 on the container of the Fancybox and I send the focus on it. This doesn't work.

```
afterLoad: function() {
    this.group[this.index].content.attr('tabindex','0');
    this.group[this.index].content.focus();
}
```

I use NVDA (NonVisual Desktop Access) http://www.nvaccess.org/ for test but Chrome can show focus too.

Thx for your help.

Comment: what type of content (inline, iframe, image)? using a form? focus on a specific form field? what is the goal to get focus in fancybox other than a form field?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It pretty much depends on the `type` of `content` but this should do the trick (using `inline`, `ajax` or `html` content)

```
$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    afterShow: function () {
        $(this.content).attr("tabindex",1).focus()
    }
});
```

It should work equally well for single or gallery elements.

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2u9a9/)** (with Chrome to make it obvious)

**NOTE**: I would advise you to use `tabindex` > `0` to avoid issues with IE (if you care about cross-browser compatibility)

**EDIT** : here an example with different type of contents : **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rmKf7/)** where `focus` is not too obvious on *images* or *iframes*

**EDIT 2** : something more general would be focusing on the `.fancybox-inner` selector regardless the type of content like

```
$(".fancybox-inner").attr("tabindex",1).focus();
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/rmKf7/1/)** but wonder if that works for your purposes

Comment: Yes it works. my content is inline html. Thx for tabindex > 1 I didn't know.

Comment: This is tested on my content (gallery content) loaded through ajax. It works perfectly with the first code piece in this post